# Python: list always appending the same element

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am making an anagrams generator. The code is explained in the comments. I don't know why the `resultArr` is always appending the same list. Sorry for my English and the inappropriate naming (should be resultList etc).

```
letterArrPermLen = len(letterArrPerm)
LastInd = letterArrPermLen
SecondLastInd = LastInd -1
resultArr = []
count=1

def Recursion(lastInd, secondLastInd):

    global count
    if lastInd == 1:
        lastInd = letterArrPermLen
    Further explained: # swap indices: # abcd acbd(swap1&2 of previous one (i.e.abcd)） acdb(swap2&3 of previous one (i.e.acbd)） # abdc(swap2&3 of the "abcd" above） adbc(swap1&2） adcb(swap2&3）
    lastInd -= 1
    secondLastInd = lastInd - 1
    # swapping elements with indices lastInd & secondLastInd
    letterArrPerm[lastInd], letterArrPerm[secondLastInd] = letterArrPerm[secondLastInd], letterArrPerm[lastInd]
    # append the swapped list to the result List
    copy = letterArrPerm
    resultArr.append(copy)

    count+=1
    # set count to 100 otherwise the recursion goes forever
    return Recursion(lastInd, secondLastInd) if count <= 100 else None


Recursion(LastInd, SecondLastInd)
print("result:　")
print(resultArr)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this code directly? I mean to modify my code to make it work.

Comment: `copy` isn't a copy, it's the same list. Use `copy = letterArrPerm[:]`

Comment: you should read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html